# Focus state is left on after a click on a navbar-link when using Firefox (works in Chrome)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

I am trying to create an in-page navigation, using the classic navbar of `Bootstrap` (`3.2`).

I am using `jQuery` to implement the scroll to functionality, plus removing and adding the `active` class to the correct tab.

**The problem**
When clicking on a navbar link when using Firefox the focus state is on (works fine with Chrome).

This is how it looks, with a normal active state:
[image: normal-active-state]

And this is how it looks after I clicked on Projects (it should look like the previous one, but it looks like the focus state is left on):
[image: erroneous-focus]

I've reproduced this behavior in [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/QJdmFWI4ZG).

Comment: I think `:focus` override your `.active`

Comment: @AndreasFurster Why would that happen? At my SCSS they are at the same level of specificity.

Answer (score 3):

Two Solutions:

1)change on focus styles:

```
.my-navbar .navbar-brand:focus {
  color: whitesmoke;
  background-color: #7d93f3;
  text-shadow: 1em;
}
```

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/benlpJ7Amq)

2)add !important to active class styles.

it will stop color and background color to be overridden on focus.

```
.my-navbar .navbar-nav > li.active > a {
  background-color: whitesmoke !important;
  color: #4e6cef !important;
}
```

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/benlpJ7Amq)

Comment: This fixes it, but it seems like an ad-hoc solution. Is the behavior I get expected?

Comment: I've already set these two rules at the specified element, and overwriting them at the `:hover`, `:active` and `:focus` states. (So the previous solution, was a bit better)